# How to set an enum not present in current iOS version?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6

I am trying to set linebreakmode for textLabel in UIButton.

```
self.scheduleButton.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
```

`NSLineBreakByWordWrapping` won't be available prior to iOS 6.0.

```
self.scheduleButton.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
```

will work prior to iOS6 but XCode is throwing an error saying, it doesn't recognize `UILineBreakModeWordWrap`.

How do I make sure that UILineBreakModeWordWrap code is completely ignored prior to iOS 6.

I have made a macro to check OS version, I would have used respondsToSelector, had it been a case with a method but this is an enum type.

```
SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"6.0")
```

I am using this here but in an if-else scenario but it wont still work as XCode will still tell me that UILineBreakModeWordWrap is not recognizable.

Is there a way I can know OS version at pre-processing level ?

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v)                ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)
```

This macro that I have made will just add Objective C code to determine OS type which means the check will happen at runtime.

but because of this XCode will not ignore `UILineBreakModeWordWrap`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping` and `UILineBreakModeWordWrap` have the same value. As long as your Base SDK is 6.0 or later then using `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping` will make the compiler happy and it will work for any version of iOS at runtime.

Comment: So he has to include OSX include files even when he's compiling for iOS?

Comment: @trojanfoe `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping` is part of iOS as of iOS 6.0. No need to include OSX headers.

Answer (score 1):

**Option:1**

You cane create your own macros to handle this:

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_6_0
# define LINE_BREAK_MODE_WORD_WRAP NSLineBreakByWordWrapping
#else
# define LINE_BREAK_MODE_WORD_WRAP UILineBreakModeWordWrap
#endif
```

Now in code you can use, **LINE_BREAK_MODE_WORD_WRAP**

**Option:2**

Directly use enum value instead of reference name, both `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping` and `UILineBreakModeWordWrap` are having same value - **0**

Hence you can directly write this way as well -

```
self.scheduleButton.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = 0;
```

It will automatically picks up 0th value from iOS SDK enumeration reference.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This compile-time solution is only useful if the same code is being compiled with multiple Base SDKs.

Comment: @rmaddy: Amogh is also doing in same way, he is checking based upon OS version, but it gives him compile time error. Hence to resolve that I guess this code snippet would be helpful.

Comment: Or else as per my second option, directly using value 0, will route to specific enum value.

Comment: I don't believe the OP wants a compile-time solution for this. There is no need for one unless the code must be compiled with two different Base SDKs (and that is a bit unlikely).

Comment: BTW - Personally, I think it is bad advice to recommend using a value of `0` directly. It may work but it makes the code less readable and harder to maintain.

Comment: @Mrunal: will checking __IPHONE_6_0 work for versions above iOS 6 ?
code will again break if I try to compile it with iOS 7.
Although your second solution of using 0 seems nice but then again that will be hardcoding.
I think rmaddy's solution is simpler, considering that iOS 7 will launch next month iOS 5 will anyways slowly slowly go away atleast it wont be the base SDK for us.